# Ifelse set new value to old variable based on logical criterias

Tags: r, if-statement

I have:

```
> select(dff_all, id, device_idom, device_model )[1:9,]
        id device_idom                device_model
1  8989419       phone        iPhone5,2 (iPhone 5)
2  6411543       phone       iPhone4,1 (iPhone 4S)
3 12521771        <NA>             XT1033 motorola
4  4507411        <NA>                        <NA>
5 13474390        <NA>            GT-I9300 samsung
6 11049297        <NA>           GT-I9300I samsung
7 14835142        <NA>                        <NA>
8 10668268       phone iPhone6,1 (iPhone 5s (GSM))
9  6991492        <NA>             XT1032 motorola
```

And I want it to be:

```
> select(dff_all, id, device_idom, device_model )[6:9,]
6 11049297        <NA>           GT-I9300I samsung
7 14835142        <NA>                        <NA>
8 10668268       phone iPhone6,1 (iPhone 5s (GSM))
9  6991492        android             XT1032 motorola
```

I want to put `device_idom = android` if `device_idom = NA` AND `device_model != NA`.

I tried this:

```
device_idom <- ifelse(
    dff_all$device_idom !== (pad | phone) 
    AND 
    is.na(dff_all$device_model) == FALSE,
    android,
    dff_all$device_idom)
```

Comment: I don't understand you expected output. Why rows 3,5:6 weren't modified too? Either way, you first need to make sure that you have real `NA`s there, and then just operate over a subset without any `if` statements. `data.table` could be a good fit for such task, e.g. `library(data.table) ; setDT(dff_all)[is.na(device_idom) & !is.na(device_model), device_idom := "android"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem probably lies in the fact that your NA's are defined as `<NA>` and not as `NA`, which might mean that they are not recognized by `R` as `NA`-values. Instead of using `is.na`, you could also use `=="<NA>"` / `!="<NA>"`.

This:

```
dff_all$device_idom <- with(dff_all, ifelse(device_idom=="<NA>" & 
                    device_model!="<NA>", "android", as.character(device_idom)))
```

should give you the desired result:

```
> dff_all
        id device_idom             device_model
1  8989419       phone       iPhone5,2(iPhone5)
2  6411543       phone      iPhone4,1(iPhone4S)
3 12521771     android           XT1033motorola
4  4507411        <NA>                     <NA>
5 13474390     android          GT-I9300samsung
6 11049297     android         GT-I9300Isamsung
7 14835142        <NA>                     <NA>
8 10668268       phone iPhone6,1(iPhone5s(GSM))
9  6991492     android           XT1032motorola
```

You can also replace `<NA>` with `NA` as follows:

```
dff_all[dff_all=="<NA>"] <- NA
```

or with:

```
is.na(dff_all) <- dff_all=="<NA>"
```

After that you should be able to use `is.na` again.

---

Doing this with `data.table` as @DavidArenburg suggested, you can use a similar logic:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dff_all)[device_idom=="<NA>" & device_model!="<NA>", device_idom := "android"]
```

---

*Note*: I removed spaces in the `device_model` column in order to read the text into a dataframe. (it's better to include the output of `dput` in your question, this will make it easier for others to help you)

Comment: What's the best way to replace <NA> with NA? Find and replace (with grep?) or import again?

Comment: or `is.na(dff_all) <- dff_all=="<NA>"`

Comment: @DavidArenburg thanx, added it to my answer

Comment: I'd suggest using `data.table` as the main solution as it both avoids evaluating the whole vector (working only on the subset), doesn't create a copy of the whole vector, avoids classes conversion and updates `device_idom` *by reference*.